# WebKit Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11

Tags: javascript, webkit

I have this code and in Firefox is working well, but in Chrome I'am getting this error:

> "Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11" at sprites.js:36

on that line is this code:

```
context.drawImage(
```

Context is a global variable in which contains 2d context of canvas. Here is full code:

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="sprites.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="prototypes.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="initialize.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body onload="initialize()">
 </body>
</html>
```

sprites.js

```
function SpritePrototype(frames, width, height, type)
{
 this.frames = frames;
 this.type = type;

 if (this.frames > 0) {
  this.frameArray = new Array(this.frames);
  for (var i = 0; i < this.frames; i++) {
   this.frameArray[i] = document.createElement("canvas");
  }
 }
}

function Sprite()
{
 this.id = 0;
 this.prototype = 0;

 this.next = 0;
 this.prev = 0;

 this.x = 0;
 this.y = 0;

 this.startFrame = 0;
 this.currentFrame = 0;
}

Sprite.prototype.draw = function()
{
 if (this.prototype == 0) {
  return;
 }
 if (context.drawImage) {
  if (this.prototype.frames > 0) {
   context.drawImage(
    this.prototype.frameArray[this.currentFrame],
    Math.round(this.x),
    Math.round(this.y)
   );
  }
 }
}
```

game.js

```
function Game()
{
 this.frameLength = 1000/30;
 this.startTime = 0;

 this.sprites = 0;
}

Game.prototype.resetTime = function()
{
 var d = new Date();
 this.startTime = d.getTime();
 delete d;
}

Game.prototype.addSprite = function(prototype)
{
 currentId++;

 if (this.sprites == 0) { // if creating the first sprite
  this.sprites = new Sprite();
  this.sprites.id = currentId;
  this.sprites.prototype = prototype;
 } else {
  var tempSprite = this.sprites; // temporarily store the first sprite
  while (tempSprite.next != 0) { // while not the last sprite
   tempSprite = tempSprite.next; // shift to next one
  }

  tempSprite.next = new Sprite(); // next sprite to the last sprite
  tempSprite.next.id = currentId;
  tempSprite.next.prototype = prototype;

  tempSprite.next.next = 0; // the last sprite, or the last one in the space
  tempSprite.next.prev = tempSprite; 
 }
}

Game.prototype.loop = function()
{
 var tempSprite;
 var currentTime;
 var globalFrame;
 var oldFrame;

 var d = new Date();
 currentTime = d.getTime();
 delete d;
 globalFrame = Math.floor((currentTime - this.startTime)/this.frameLength);

 canvas.width = canvas.width;

 tempSprite = this.sprites;
 while (tempSprite != 0) {
  if (tempSprite.frames > 0) {
   oldFrame = tempSprite.currentFrame;
   tempSprite.currentFrame = globalFrame;
  }

  tempSprite.draw();

  tempSprite = tempSprite.next;
 }
}
```

prototypes.js

```
var protoPlayer;

function createPrototypes()
{
 var tempCtx;
 var i;

 protoPlayer = new SpritePrototype(5, 20, 30, "player");
 for (i = 0; i < protoPlayer.frames; i++) {
  protoPlayer.frameArray[i].width = protoPlayer.width;
  protoPlayer.frameArray[i].height = protoPlayer.height;
  tempCtx = protoPlayer.frameArray[i].getContext("2d");
  tempCtx.strokeStyle = "rgb("+ i * 50 +", 0, 0)";
  tempCtx.beginPath();
  tempCtx.moveTo(0, 0);
  tempCtx.lineTo(20, 30);
  tempCtx.stroke();
 }
}
```

initialize.js

```
var game;

var canvas;
var context;

var currentId;

function initialize()
{
 canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
 canvas.width = 640;
 canvas.height = 480;
 canvas.setAttribute("style", "background:#060606;");
 document.body.appendChild(canvas);
 context = canvas.getContext("2d");

 createPrototypes();

 currentId = 0;

 game = new Game();

 game.addSprite(protoPlayer);

 game.loop(); 
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Seems to me that that error is happening because you are calling drawImage with a HTMLCanvasObject who's height or width is zero. From the latest canvas 2d context spec:

> If the image argument is an
>   HTMLCanvasElement object with either a
>   horizontal dimension or a vertical
>   dimension equal to zero, then the
>   implementation must raise an
>   INVALID_STATE_ERR exception.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/2dcontext/#images

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'am setting width and height in initialize function. And in Firefox is this code working. What is different between Firefox and Chrome? :(

Comment: @nesro Not on the `HTMLCanvasElements` inside of frameArray

Comment: in prototype.js is:   protoPlayer.frameArray[i].width = protoPlayer.width;
  protoPlayer.frameArray[i].height = protoPlayer.height;

Comment: @nestro Yep, missed that. Well, if you log the height and width at the time of drawImage you will see that they are 0, so setting them isn't working (or possibly not happening)

Comment: Yes.. I'am dumb. I forgoted in SpritePrototype to set width and height from construtor arguments. Sory for your time, but very very thanks. I  had rewriten more longer to to this short code to find bug. I will never do again write more code without in progress testing. These bugs are terrible. Thank you again! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Some time this error also occurred when we try to do `document.getElemetnById('xx').innerHtml='htmlcode';` in this time '`htmlcode`' should be proper formatted mean should use proper closing tags.